# AnkhSVN: No Versioned Parent Directories when adding a Web Site

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, web, ankhsvn

I've recently been trying out Ankhsvn and I quite like it, and more importantly, it generally likes me.

But I've hit a problem adding existing VS projects to subversion using AnkhSVN. Most Windows and Web projects are added fine, but I have a problem when I try to a Websites (as opposed to Web Applications), and in these cases I get the following error:

```
No versioned parent directories
```

After some googling, I've come across other people with the same problems and there have been one or two suggests for solving the problem, but non so far have worked.

AnkhSVN is popular enough, and although web applications are often preferred to websites these days, I'm hoping that someone here has a ready solution available.

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Whatever the latest version was, as of a week ago- v2.1.xxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause for this is that web sites don't share a common root with the solution. Adding a new solution to Subversion automatically requires them to share a common root (for now).

You can manually add the projects to the correct positions in the Subversion repository, and AnkhSVN will recognize them. The problem with this is that your layout doesn't have to match that of a fellow developer. Therefor the best solution is to move the website to a directory in the solution root, just like projects.